# How to generate html link for creating recurring event on Google Calendar?

Tags: html, google-calendar-api

**Use case**: Help setting up users set up daily & recurring reminders for their medicines on their Google calendar. The HTML link will be shared in an email.

I trying to generate an HTML link that helps users to quickly set-up a (local) reminder on their own account calendar. While many tools are available to generate a link for a single reminder / event (with relevant details like date and time), I am unable to find syntax for adding recurrence rule to the link.

*Example for non-recurring event* - [Link](http://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE&dates=20201125T010000Z%2F20201125T020000Z&text=Test&location=&details=Dekh&)

I just need to edit the link above to add the recurrence rule. Kindly help.

Answer (score 9):

Add to your URL `&recur=RRULE:` and the specify the rule in an URL encoded syntax:

**Example:**

```
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/eventedit?dates=20201125T010000Z/20201125T020000Z&text=Test&location&details=Dekh&recur=RRULE:FREQ%3DDAILY
```